# Trying to send POST request with Postman but getting CastError

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to send a POST request using Postman but getting a CastError.
Why can't I just send the patient and provider fields as strings? Is this the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/query_casting.html#query-casting) I should be looking at?

I've seen solutions, but my server crashes. Here are two:

```
const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.patient)

or

import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
const convertedId = ObjectId(req.body.patient)
```

This is the request I am trying to send:

```
{
    "patient": "StackOverFlow",
    "provider": "MariaMorales",
    "startTime": "1660572900250",
     "endTime": "1660573800250"
}
```

The error:

```
{
    "message": {
        "errors": {
            "patient": {
                "stringValue": "\"StackOverFlow\"",
                "valueType": "string",
                "kind": "ObjectId",
                "value": "StackOverFlow",
                "path": "patient",
                "reason": {},
                "name": "CastError",
                "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"StackOverFlow\" (type string) at path \"patient\" because of \"BSONTypeError\""
            }
        },
        "_message": "Appointment validation failed",
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Appointment validation failed: patient: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"StackOverFlow\" (type string) at path \"patient\" because of \"BSONTypeError\""
    }
}
```

Models:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface isAppointment {
    // patient: string;
    // provider: string;
    startTime: Date;
    endTime: Date;
}

const AppointmentSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    patient: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Patient' },
    provider: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Provider' },
    startTime: { type: Date, required: true },
    endTime: { type: Date, required: true }
});

export default mongoose.model<isAppointment>('Appointment', AppointmentSchema);
```

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface isPatient {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    surname: string;
}

const PatientSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        _id: { type: String, required: true },
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        surname: { type: String, required: true }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model<isPatient>('Patient', PatientSchema);
```

The Controller Fnc:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import Appointment from '../models/Appointment';

const createAppointment = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const appointment = new Appointment(req.body);
        await appointment.save();
        return res.status(200).json(appointment);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error });
    }
};

export default { createAppointment };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `objectId` documentation.
[ObjectId - MongoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

You can not cast a string to ObjectId if it is not hexadecimal. So, you can not save stack overflow as your ObjectId.

To generate a valid ObjectId use the code below:

```
const generateObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const objectId = new generateObjectId();
```

Comment: Quick question: Why do I need to generate a new ObjectId if I'm trying to reference one already existing? The patient and provider exist in the DB. Can't I save or reference their _id inside the appointment?

Comment: @Selloum what you are trying to save as an ObjectId is not a valid one. If your unique id is of a onother type so change your key type in the destination collection. But if you have a valid ObjectId in the reference collection you need to pass that to your request.

Comment: Got it! I had saved the _id as a string and didn't know I could do this: patient: { type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Patient' }. Now it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Because I had overwritten the _id property of my patient and provider models to `String`, I needed to reference their type. Thanks, Pooya Raki!

Answer:

```
const AppointmentSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        patient: { type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Patient' },
        provider: { type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Provider' },
        startTime: { type: Date, required: true },
        endTime: { type: Date, required: true }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```